# GCP Flexible Python Environment: Import Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy, app-engine-flexible

today i tried to setup my first App Engine App using the flexible environment for Python. First of all i followed the hello_world example which worked fine.

But then i tried to use numpy which is not working on my local machine, but if i deploy the app to GAE it works as expected.

Whenever i trie to start the app on my local machine by using

`python main.py`

I get the Error

`(env) *-MBP:hello_world *$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in 
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy`

But I made sure to add numpy to the requirements.txt file and also pip installed it in the virtualenv manually.

Does someone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**

My main.py looks like this:

```
import logging  
import numpy as np  
from flask import Flask    

app = Flask(`__name__`)  

@app.route('/')  
def hello():
    return str(np.array([1, 2, 3]))  


if `__name__` == '`__main__`':  
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=1111, debug=True)
```

Comment: You need to create a `lib` folder inside the project's root directory.. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27 And then you have to install all the packages to that lib folder ;like `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this below line in your **main.py** file.

```
import numpy
```

This should fix the issue. !!!

Under your virtual env, try installing numpy again by this line.

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast reply. But unfortunately this doesn't change anything because i already imported numpy. 

The exact error message I get is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: Can u just post your code, so that everyone can have a clarity on it...

Comment: try installing numpy again in virtual env

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling numpy worked finally.

But first I had to uninstall numpy with

`pip uninstall numpy`

after that reinstalling numpy with

`pip install numpy`

solved my issue.

Thank you for all the help.